# Is legacy winsock available for windows store apps?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winsock

I know that code on windows store which used socket needed to use the StreamSocket class instead of the legacy winsock API (Socket class)

And it is clearly something that prevent me from migrating my open source library whose lots of app would depends.

Now, I've seen that [VS 2013 update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2014-aug-4-vs.aspx) add "winsock support", also announced [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/13/winsock-and-more-open-source-for-your-windows-store-apps/).

Does it means that I can use exactly the goold old and loved Socket ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the bulk of the winsock APIs are available for both Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.x Store Apps (and of course Universal Windows Apps in Windows 10). There are still some restrictions around access to loopback addresses etc. but the APIs should be available to you.

Comment: thanks, excellent news. It is exactly what prevented me to port my lib to winrt.